# Why does exiting with a stored returncode of a nested command result in different returncodes in Dash and Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, subshell, exit-status, dash

Running

```
bash -c 'bash -c "echo test1; exit 1;" &> /tmp/x; buildresult=$?; tail -n 100 /tmp/x; exit $buildresult;'
```

results in `test1` being printed to console and `echo $?` to print `1` which in my understanding is correct, because the command should return with what the inner `[b/d]ash -c` returned whereas

```
dash -c 'dash -c "echo test1; exit 1;" &> /tmp/x; buildresult=$?; tail -n 100 /tmp/x; exit $buildresult;'
```

results in the same output, but returns with `0` according to `echo $?`.

I'd like to understand this difference in order to broaden my understanding of shells and portable shell programming.

I'm using `bash` 4.4.12 and `dash` 0.5.8-2.3ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`&>` redirection is not in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07) and isn't supported by `dash`. It's parsed as `& >`, so the command is backgrounded instead. [Backgrounded commands are given an exit status of zero](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_03) from the perspective of the parent, since they haven't exited by the time you read `$?`.

That's also why (for me at least) the "`test1`" output appears in my prompt, *after* the command has finished.

[Bash's `&> foo` is equivalent to `> foo 2>&1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error), and a portable script should use the latter.

Comment: `&>` is in POSIX. That's `&` followed by `>`. In `foo &> bar`, that's `foo &` to start `foo` in background and `> bar` to perform a redirection without a command. `bash` is not POSIX compliant when it's interpreting it differently.

Comment: Interesting enough is that this  wasn't mentioned in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh   I took a liberty to edit the page and include that